# How should I set up tests for a testing framework?

Tags: c#, testing, tdd, mstest

I am currently in the process of putting together a relatively lightweight framework for helping specify expected code coverage and to guarantee that that coverage is met (or explicitly stated as not needed).

However, testing the framework when automatically implemented tests *should* fail is slightly tricky, because normally, you want passing tests to be a good thing and failing tests to be a bad thing.

An example is:

```
public interface IDesigned {
    void DoFoo();
}

[ClassTestRequirements(Targets.Methods, "IsNotImplemented")]
public interface ITestsOfDesigned : IDesigned
{
}

public class Foo : IDesigned 
{
}

[TestClass]
[AdoptsTestRequirements(typeof(ITestsOfDesigned), typeof(IDesigned))]
public class Tester : ProvidesCoverageFor<Foo>
{
   /* 
    *  Validation that Tester does what it's supposed to (it currently 
    *  doesn't) is set up in the base class.
    */
}
```

ProvidesCoverage is an abstract base class that includes a test method that validates using the above that Tester has a method in it decorated with `[Covers(nameof(IDesigned.DoFo), "IsNotImplemented")]` that does whatever it does - that's not checked. There's also a mechanism whereby a test tester can be set up to check that all classes decorated with `IProvidesCoverage<>` actually validate their tests.

Obviously in the above, the scenario *should* be that the `ProvidesCoverage<>.ValidateTests()` fails. What's more it feels like a valid test to want to perform. But ideally I'd like to configure a scenario where those tests aren't necessarily treated as actual tests (despite being decorated with `TestClass`/`TestMethod` etc.) but that an external (actual) test runs them and expects a failure.

How can I get that? And if I can't, how *should* I be testing a project like this, given that, since the intention is to cause certain tests to fail, failure IS a legitimate pass sometimes.

Comment: If a test fails your tested code is **wrong** - Period. Code coverage is one important detail of many. My unit tests have sometimes 8 to 10 tests for a single method and all of them are important and none of them could be removed. Code coverage would not help in that case to detect a missing test

Comment: code coverage is not the goal.  In fact it's dangerous to make it a goal, it's easy to get coverage, harder to get tests that validate what was covered, worse not knowing if it was not well tested because someone made it get coverage

Comment: I've just used the approach to allow me to guarantee to myself that I did implement tests against all test-requiring members of another project, so whatever the typical position, I can say from first hand usage that it is certainly *useful* to have a test that fails when insufficient testing is taking place. It means you can indicate to yourself that you're not looking at something, and therefore might not have thought what (might) need to be tested there. In practice, it works. It's just I can't easily write anything to prove that future change haven't broken it. Who watches the watchmen etc.

Comment: I also find it useful to look at coverage, but I don't make it fail anything.

Comment: I went down this route primarily because I was building increasingly (and unexpectedly) complex interfaces that I could foresee would interweave in many interesting ways, some of which I'd expect to forget about when I later came to write tests. So wanted to be able to say "Hey, future me, write this test", and be told off if I didn't. Also bear in mind I'm on VS community edition: most *actual* coverage tools cost and take significant setup. This, I decorate a couple of things and add a test class that inherits from the test tester, and I get some idea what's going on.

Comment: Add a TODO to all classes/interfaces with "Write tests"

Comment: well perhaps it's better handled some way that doesn't fail tests as you are arguing to have legitimately failing tests.  That gets in the way of doing TDD.  Perhaps have another build phase that validates what you want ( I've seen teams who adopt UT put a build step in that validates coverage doesn't go down )

Comment: Do bear in mind I'm not arguing to have legitimately failing tests in any project I'm using this for. They'd pass when the appropriate tests had been written. I'm just arguing that a test that tests tests should confirm that it does in fact cause failures to happen when you'd expect them to (e.g. when the other tests aren't there).

Comment: Do not bother with code coverage. Code coverage only for developers who write tests after they write production code. If you write test first - your test coverage will be always 100%. if you write tests after - you need some how to check that your test will fail if something changes in the production code - so you will change it.

Comment: If you do TDD (i.e Test first, code second), you never need worry about coverage again - High coverage will be a byproduct of a very good and extensive test suite.